# Use a power bank instead of batteries for a LEGO train

Tags: power-supply, voltage, batteries, battery-charging, amperage

I'm tired of charging and charging batteries for my LEGO train. It takes 6 AAA batteries. I have several questions:

1. 6xAAA means the motor needs 9V, right?
2. When using rechargeables they only supply something like 1.2V, so the motor is slower? Or are the batteries empty more rapidly? How does that work?
3. I want to use a power bank that has fast charge ability (ie supply 9V) and hook that up. How do the AMPs play into this? And will that automatically switch to fast charge (9V, 2A) when the motor needs that?

Comment: 1. Not necessarily. 2. One or the other, depends on how the train works. 3. You're going to have to give more information on that. Probably not.

Comment: If you train is not powered by the track then flip it over so the train still works but remains in one place and use a multimeter to measure the current it needs. If the batteries only supply 2A and the train pulls like 1.8A then yes your supply is way too low in terms of the amperage rating of the battery.

Comment: Unless you somehow modified the train to communicate with the power bank and actively request 9 V, you're not going to get 9 V from it.

Comment: @Hearth: 1: what does it depend on? How to find out? 2: How to find out? 3:What info do you need? Thanks

Comment: @Joey, do I measure the battery pack output? Not quite sure what to do (I'm new to this, sorry)

Comment: @Peete watch a youtube video on how to measure current using a multimeter.

Comment: For a usb power bank with fast charge (QC2, 3, PD whatever) you'll need to get a fast charge trigger module. A few bucks on the usual sites, it will enable the 9V or other options for you. That or buy a power bank that has a voltage switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 6xAAA means the motor needs 9V, right?

Give or take, yes. The nominal voltage of a AAA battery is 1.5V, so 6 in series is 9V nominal. In practice AAA's are more like 1.6V fresh giving the lower bound of the motors max voltage rating of 9.6V. Furthermore a typically AAA battery terminal voltage is around 1.3V or so under load for most of its capacity, so the motor should run fine at 7.8V, albeit slightly slower.

> When using rechargeables they only supply something like 1.2V, so the motor is slower? Or are the batteries empty more rapidly? How does that work?

With the lower voltage (7.2V), a simple brushed DC motor will simply run slower, possibly to the point of stalling. It really depends on the motor whether or not it will work. You are unlikely to damage anything by using rechargable batteries in this application.

From experience, LEGO motors will run off rechargable batteries OK.

> I want to use a power bank that has fast charge ability (ie supply 9V) and hook that up. How do the AMPs play into this?

I've split the last paragraph in two as the questions are distinct.

You will need to find out what the current draw of the motors is to be able to determine how much current your supply needs to be capable of delivering. There are three ways of doing this, one is experimental, one is guesswork, one is research.

1. Use a current meter in series with the motor when powered from your AAA batteries to measure how much current it uses. You will want to apply some load to the motor (e.g. pressing it down on the LEGO track) as the current will increase when the motor is doing more work.
2. Make an assumption about AAA batteries. A typical AAA battery can't really maintain more than ~1**A** continuous (don't confuse this with the rated capacity in **mAh**). Based on that, as long as your power supply can provide at least 1A of current you will likely be fine.
3. Find somebody who has measured it. For example, [experimental results here](https://www.philohome.com/ttrain/ttrain.htm) show the current draw is around 160mA with low load, going up to around 200mA or so under higher load. And that also shows a 9V lego motor tested at 5.4V. So as long as your supply can give lets say 250mA or more, you should be fine.

> And will that automatically switch to fast charge (9V, 2A) when the motor needs that?

This depends on what you mean by a fast charge power supply.

If it is a simple 9V rechargable battery pack, then it will provide 9V by design.

If you are referring to modern mobile phone or laptop chargers (e.g. USB power delivery), then no. Such a charger will not switch automatically. They require some form of control (e.g. resistor values, or PD controller) to select a voltage.

You would need to find out what your power supply uses to select the voltage it uses, and implement whatever is required to switch it to supply 9V.

Comment: I'll try the experimental path first!

Answer (score 0):

1. > 6xAAA means the motor needs 9V, right?

   Yes, provided each AAA is rated at 1.5V
2. > When using rechargeables they only supply something like 1.2V, so the motor is slower? Or are the batteries empty more rapidly? How does that work?

   The battery will last longer if it as higher current capacity. Let's say you have 6 1.5V batteries rated at 500mA and you connect them in series. Then effectively you now have a 9V 500mA battery because it is connected in series.

   On the other hand, if you have 6 1.5V but now rated at 1000mA and connect it in series you will now have a 9V 1000mA battery. But the 1000mA will last longer than the 500mA because is as higher current capacity.
3. > I want to use a power bank that has fast charge ability (ie supply 9V) and hook that up. How do the AMPs play into this? And will that automatically switch to fast charge (9V, 2A) when the motor needs that?

   If the powerbank it rated at 5000mAh and your trains consumes 200mA then your train will last 25 hours assuming no losses. Now regarding the fast charge. Obvisoulsy if you increase the speed of the train, the motor will pull more current. So lets say at 5m/s the train pulls 20mA and at 15m/s the train will pull 150mA, now the power bank will still supply the 150mA to the train.

Answer (score -1):

A power bank usually has a 5V output to feed the charger circuit in a phone. Since your train needs 9V then with only 5V it will run slowly.
The power bank has a battery in it that can be charged quickly which has no effect on the train's motor.
You did not say what voltage and current charges the powerbank. Most charge from USB 5V.

Comment: I would get one that charges from 9V if that helped

Comment: e.g. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32825723715.html